# Linked list to contain strings in c

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct node
{
    char *IPArray[100];
    struct node *ptr;
};
typedef struct node NODE;

NODE *head, *first, *temp = 0;

first = 0;

int numofIP;
```

This is my structure to contain string at every node in a linked list. And numofIP is maximum number of strings or nodes in my linked list.

```
for(int i=0; i<numofIP; i++)
{
    head  = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    printf("enter the IP addresses:\n");
    scanf("%s",&head->IPArray[i]);

    if(first != 0)
    {
        temp->ptr = head;
        temp = head;
    }
    else
    {
        first = temp = head;
    }
}

temp->ptr = 0;
temp  = first;
```

this is how I accept input and store it in every node.

```
while(temp != NULL)
{
    printf("%d=> ",temp->IPArray);
    temp = temp->ptr;
}
```

And this is how I print the linked list.

But problem is I get addresses in output. I am not able to figure it out.  How to store a string in each node in a linked list?

Comment: `char *IPArray[100];` → `char IPArray[100];`, `scanf("%s",&head->IPArray[i]);` → `scanf("%s", head->IPArray[i]);`, `printf("%d=> ",temp->IPArray);`→ `printf("%s=> ",temp->IPArray);`

Comment: [don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Your character array "char *IPArray[100] "is actually an array of character pointers.It stores character addresses.

Answer (score 2):

**1**.Change

`printf("%d=> ",temp->IPArray);`

to

`printf("%s=> ",temp->IPArray);`

You have given incorrect format specifier to `printf` function.

**2**.Allocate memory for each `char*` in `IPArray`.

But, As you have mentioned you need only one string in a node then change
`char* IPArray[100]` to `char IPArray[100]`

`char* IPArray[100]`  : will create pointers to 100 strings for which you need to allocate memory later on.

`char IPArray[100]`   : will create array of 100 characters in which you can store IP address for particular node and you don't need to allocate separate memory for that.

Answer (score 0):

> Replace your **while loop** with the following loop.It should work.And
>   dont forget to initialise j=0;

```
 while(temp != NULL)
{
    printf("%s=> ",&temp->IPArray[j]);
    temp = temp->ptr;
j++;

}
```